# Rails mailer "undefined method" error.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailer

I'm trying to setup a simple mailer in rails 3.1.

I have the following code in my mailer...

```
class Notify < ActionMailer::Base

  default :from => "signup@raceton.com"

  def send
    @email = email
    @ip = ip
    mail(:to => "test@test.com", :subject => "#{email} just signed up")
  end

end
```

Then in my controller I have...

```
Notify.send(params[:email], ip).deliver
```

For some reason that I can't work out when that line is called in my controller I get the following error...

```
undefined method `*string I passed in*' for Notify:Class
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

send() is already defined by Ruby, and it is used to pass messages around.

So, to ruby it looks like you are trying to call a method.

```
User.first.send(:name)
```

is the same thing as calling

```
User.first.name
```

Just rename your method.

Comment: really?! dang.. quite a time-saver.. Thanks Unixmonkey